# Testing if multiple independent low-rate counting processes are poisson

Tags: independence, poisson-process

I have multiple independent counting processes and I want to check if they generally behave like Poisson processes. For the sake of the example, imagine a city with $N$ citizens and $M$ shops, where each citizen $i$ independently wanders around the city between $s_i$ and $e_i$,  and enters a shop from time to time.
I have the data of when and which citizens entered shops, **but not** which shop they've entered. Also, no parameters are known and everything is assumed from the data.

I want to test whether 'shop entering' can be described as Poisson processes, either by addressing each citizen separately or by pooling them together.

Options I considered:

1. Checking each citizen $i$ separately, and testing whether their arrival times at shops are distributed randomly-uniformly between $s_i$ and $e_i$, to conclude that $i$'s 'shop entering' process is or isn't Poisson. I believe this would be ideal, as I could say that 'X% of all citizens have a shop-entering process that is a Poisson process'. The problem is, in many cases the total number of entrances by a single citizen is very low (say 1 or 2), so I don't see how I could create a test
   for these citizens if I choose this approach.
2. Checking all citizens together; scaling their time in the city between 0 and 1, and then scaling their 'arrival times' accordingly. For instance,

   - citizen $i$: $s_i=20$, $e_i=30$, entered shops at $t=23, 27, 29$ -> add $[0.3, 0.7, 0.9]$ to the total pool of arrivals.
   - citizen $j$: $s_j=10$, $e_j=50$, and entered a shop at $t=20$ -> add $[0.25]$ to the total pool of arrivals.

Then, I could run a single test on the total pool of arrivals $([0.25, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9]$ in this case, but $N>1000$ so we could expect a much longer list) and see if it's uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. Will this test hold?

Are there other suggestions to perform this?

Comment: No, You wouldn't test whether data are Poisson by using a uniform null hypothesis. My answer outlines a method using a chi-squared test.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean testing on the exponential distribution instead (for time between events)? If so, is there a way to perform the chi-squared test on the entire population at once? Since I would still have the same problem for testing each citizen separately

Comment: I understood that you want to test the numbers of visits in a particular period of time of the 'total pool' citizens to see if the counts are consistent with some Poisson distribution. This is my approach in the Answer just now finished. // If this is a Poisson process, the interarrival times would be exponential with rate λ.

Comment: @BruceET thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have $n = 1000$ observations from $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 5).$
[Note: in some circumstances, one might estimate $\lambda$ directly from these data, as 4.968, but that estimate is not valid for our test whether the data fit
a Poisson distribution.]

```
set.seed(2021)
x = rpois(1000, 5)
table(x)
x
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13 
  5  46  90 137 164 180 140 100  62  40  23   8   4   1 
mean(x)
[1] 4.968
```

**Categories.** You might decide to put the counts for $X = 11,12,$ and $13$ together in to a final cell "$\ge 11$". [For some Poisson data you might need to combine some small counts in the left tail as well, but that's not necessary here.]

**Estimated Poisson mean.** *Using these $12$ categories,* estimate $\lambda.$
You might use values $v_j = (0,1,2,\dots,9,10,12)$ and
frequencies $f_j = c(5,46,90,\dots,40,23,13).$

Then the formula $\hat \lambda = \bar X = \frac{1}{1000}\sum_{j=0}^{11} f_jv_j.,$ all based odn $\hat\lambda.$

**Category probabilities and expected counts.** Find probabilities of the $k=12$ categories as $p_j; j=0,\dots,10$
as $p_j = P(X = j|\hat\lambda)$ and $p_{11} = P(X >= 10|\hat\lambda).$
Then the twelve category expected counts are $E_j=np_j,$ for $j=0, \dots 11.$ [Note, if you use the original 1000 counts to estimate $\lambda,$ then the chi-squared statistic $Q$ found below may not have the intended distribution.]

**Chi-squared statistic and test.** The test statistic is
$Q = \sum_{i=0}^{11}\frac{(f_j-E_j)^2}{Ej},$ which has approximately
the distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 10).$ The degrees of freedom
are $\nu = k - 2 = 10.$ If we were checking for fit to a Poisson distribution with known $\lambda,$ then we would have $\nu= k-1,$ but by estimating
$\lambda$ by $\hat\lambda,$ the degrees of freedom are decreased by $1.$
$H_0$ that the data follow some Poisson distribution is rejected if
$Q > 18.31.$

```
qchisq(.95, 10)
[1] 18.30704
```

Computations:

```
f = c(5,46,90,137,164,180,140,100,62,40,23,13) 
v = c(0:10, 12)
lam.est = sum(f*v)/1000;  lam.est
[1] 4.975
p = c(dpois((0:10),lam.est),sum(dpois((11:13),lam.est)))
E = 1000*p;  E
[1]   6.908519  34.369882  85.495081 141.779342 176.338057 175.456367
[7] 145.482571 103.396541  64.299724  35.543459  17.682871  12.581965
q= sum((f-E)^2/E);  q
[1] 8.414
```

---

Note: I'm not exactly sure what you were trying to do with
exponential and uniform distributions toward the end of your question. Here
is a possibly relevant simulation.

```
set.seed(211)
u = runif(1001);  w = diff(sort(u))
hist(w, prob=T, br=20, ylim=c(0,1000), col="skyblue2", main="")
curve(dexp(x,1000), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2, n=10001)
```

[image]